# How do I return a JsonResponse if the post data is bad in tastypie?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

For example, client post a card number in data and I use it to fetch the card record from database. If it does not exist, I return a JsonResponse such as:

`return JsonResponse({
    success:False,
    msg:'The card does not exsit! Please check the card number.'
    })`

If the card does exist, I will use it to filter another record from database and use them togeter to create the obj such as an consumption record.

I read the docs of tastypie but have no idea how to control the HttpResponse that tastypie finally returned.

Comment: Your `JsonResponse` here is django's `HttpResponse` subclass, right?

Comment: Yes，now I just raise a ImmediateHttpResponse in hydrate method for a temporary solution. I don't no is there any elegent way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're returning django's [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects), you can simply return it with appropriate [status](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.status_code), just like with `HttpResponse`.

Comment: Thanks! But the question is where return it. For example, in hydrate method it except to return a bundle object. If I return a HttpResponse, it will throw an exception.